# wcf REST Ping timeout

Tags: wcf, rest, ping

i have set my IIS Authentification = Basic, and create account windows with login = pda and password = xxx.

but when my client acces into my service, i got message timeout

```
 public Stream PingServer()
        {

            //string LeUrl = "http://localhost:81/Code/WcfService_REST_SuiviColis/WcfService_REST_SuiviColis/Service1.svc";
            string LeUrl = "http://xxx.YYY.ZZZ/FA85/Service1.svc/";
            string Result = "",ErrPb="";
            try
            {
                var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LeUrl);

                myRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("pda", "xxx");
                myRequest.Method = "PUT";
                myRequest.ContentLength = 0;

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // Si le serveur OK
                    Result = "OK - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                }
                else
                {
                    //  Sinon on a le problem
                    Result = "KO - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    ErrPb = response.StatusDescription + System.Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // encore un autre problem             
                Result = "KO - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                ErrPb += ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }
```

when i deleted this code:

```
myRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("pda", "xxx");
                myRequest.Method = "PUT";
```

i got error 401  : Authentification failed

when i deleted this code :

```
myRequest.ContentLength = 0;
```

i got error 411 : length required.

but now, i got timeout delayed had expired

and my web.config:

```
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService_REST_SuiviColis.Service1" >
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService_REST_SuiviColis.IService1"  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>    
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>           
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />                   
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>   
    </behaviors>

   <bindings>
       <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
           receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
           sendTimeout="00:10:00"
           openTimeout="00:10:00"
           closeTimeout="00:10:00">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"  />                 
            </security>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>


<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    <serviceActivations>
        <add
          factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
            relativeAddress="Service1.svc"
            service="WcfService_REST_SuiviColis.Service1" />
    </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Windows account against the Basic authentication. You should set IIS authentication with Windows Auth.

Comment: thanks, but how can i make just basic authentification